# XFORMS INPUT CHECKING

Tags: redirect, input, xforms, typechecking

I want the user to input data in my xforms:input field and check it while the user is typing whether the input is decimal or not and If it is not decimal then show an error message and take the control back to that input box so that user can again type in it.

I want to do checking without using any scripts. I only want to use features of XFORMS only for checking while user is typing.

FOR redirecting control back to that input box after showing message I can use javascript, but would preferably want to do it using features of XFORMS only.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Validation_with_Bind

this example show how to check and redirect and alert the user using only XFORMS features

Answer (score 0):

en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Validation_with_Bind

this example show how to check and redirect and alert the user using only XFORMS features